# Gamma bridge sampling in R

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to bridge sampling to sample a gamma process for the interval (0:T) for a 2^{m} partition length.T=T_{2^m}, m=number of bridges. I am using R studio but my results are all NA's, can someone please help me, I have attached a picture of the algorithm.

```
set.seed(1) 
M <- 7
nt <- 2^M + 1 #number of observations
T <- nt - 1 #total time
T_ <- seq(0, T, length.out=nt) #fixed time increments
G_[T] <- rgamma(1, shape=T/nu, scale=nu)
G_[1] <- 0
for (m in 1:M){
  for (j in 2:2^(m-1)){
     i <- (2*j-1)
     Y <- rbeta(1,T/(nu*2^m), T/(nu*2^m))
     G_[i*T/2^m] <- G_[(i-1)^T/2^m] + (G_[(i+1)*T/2^m] - G_[(i-1)*T/2^m])*Y
       }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: also by nu is 0.1184

Comment: At iteration 1 (m = j = 1), the index into G_[(i-1)^T/2^m] will be G_[0], but R is 1-indexed. Maybe that's causing it? How did you initialize G_?

Comment: G_ is a matrix of length nt

Comment: Is the issue that your code raises everything to the power T, but the pseudocode only multiplies by T? (Also, my bad, your indexing for the first iteration was okay).

Comment: Hello, thank you for you replies. the star sign indicate multiplication?

Comment: Yes, but in `G_[(i-1)^T/2^m]`, you raise to the power `T`.

Comment: oh wow thank you, i didn't notice it !

Comment: Also, I think if you index into a list using strings, you can directly use the pseudocode's fractional indexing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218321/discussion-between-mandy-mandy-and-krisrs1128).